# If $X\sim Unif[0,1]$ what is $f_Y$ if $Y=g(X)$?

Tags: probability

Let $X\sim Uniform[0,1]$ and $$g(x)=\begin{cases}3x&x\in [0,1/3]\\ 0&otherwise\end{cases}.$$
What is the density function of $Y$ ? (denoted $f_Y$).

---

I'm a bit confuse. The cumulative function is given by $$F_Y(y)=\mathbb P\{Y\leq y\}=\mathbb P\{g(X)\leq y\},$$
but I have problem to continue. Is it $$\mathbb P\{G(X)\leq y\}=\mathbb P\{G(X)\leq y, X\in [0,1]\}$$
$$=\mathbb P\{g(X)\leq y,X\in[0,1/3]\}+\mathbb P\{g(X)\leq y, X\in [1/3,1]\}=\mathbb P\{3X\leq y, X\in [0,1/3]\}+\mathbb P\{0\leq y,X\in [1/3,1]\} \ \ ?$$

I'm confuse on how to continue.

Answer (score 2):

The truth is $Y$ has no density function, since it's not a continuous random variable. It's actually not a discrete one, either.

Note that $P(Y=0)=P\left(X\notin \left[0,\frac13\right]\right)=\frac23$, so $Y$ is not continuous, since it has positive probability in one point ($Y=0$), but this is the only point with non-zero probability, so that $Y$ can't be discrete (because only $\frac23$ of the probability are accumulated at points, the other $\frac13$ is continuously accumulated in the interval $(0,1)$.

That is, $Y$ has a mixed type probability distribution.

While it has no PDF nor PMF, it has a CDF (any random variable does) and it is 
$$F_Y(y)=\left\{\begin{matrix}0 & y<0\\ \frac23+\frac y3 & 0\le y<1\\ 1 & y\ge 1.\end{matrix}\right.$$

Comment: Nice answer. I was in the wrong way since the beginning. (+1)

Comment: But for $y\in (0,1)$ can't we say that $f_Y(y)=\frac{1}{3}$ ? (i.e. it has a density for all $y\in (0,1)$ ?

Comment: Well... that would not be a density since it does not integrate $1$. We could say that $Y$ has a density conditioned on $Y\neq 0$, though, but that density would be $1$, not $\frac 13$. If $Y\neq 0$, then $Y\sim \mathbb U(0,1)$, but if $Y=0$, then... well... then $Y=0$, and that's it.

Comment: Another way to see a mixed r.v. is to take a r.v. $U$ which is $0$ with probability $\frac13$ and $1$ with probability $\frac23$ (that is, a _Bernoulli_ r.v. with $p=\frac23$). Then define:
$$Y=\left\{\begin{matrix}W& U=0\\ 0 & U=1\\\end{matrix}\right.$$

Answer (score 0):

A simpler approach is

$$
f_X{\rm d}X = f_Y {\rm d}Y ~~\Rightarrow ~~~ f_Y(y) = f_X(x)\left|\frac{{\rm d}X}{{\rm d}Y}\right|  = 1 \cdot \frac{1}{3} = \frac{1}{3}
$$